# "Save Link As" saves the file as a wrong file type on Edge/Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, download, microsoft-edge

We have local websites that store .CSV files for machines productivity. Our company has forced us to move off Internet Explorer and now we can only use Edge/Chrome. On Internet Explorer, when you would right click and do "Save Link As" it would save it as a .csv file type, the proper file type. But on the edge/chrome, it saves it as a text file.

Is there any way I can put a setting in my machine or browser to always save the files on these sites as a .csv?

Cheers,

Finlay

I have searched online for other similar issues, but none seem to appear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my research, if the mime type for csv file is text/plain on server side, it couldn't be saved as .csv format. If it is text/csv, you could directly save it as .csv file.

So please kindly check the mine mapping on your Server side.

Alternatively, you could open that sites in IE mode in Edge. Before that, you need to enable "**Allow Save Target As in Internet Explorer mode**" group policy. Please refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-faq#can-i-save-links-as-webpages-in-internet-explorer-mode) for details.

Answer (score 0):

To define the MIME type for the browser to open a "Save Link As..." dialog, you can use the text/csv media type as defined in [RFC 7111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7111).

For example to do so in C#, you can use the following code:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=YourFile.csv");
```

The first header sets the content type to text/csv, which tells the browser that the response contains a CSV file. The second header sets the Content-Disposition header, which specifies that the browser should display a "Save Link As..." dialog and suggest the filename "YourFile.csv" for the downloaded file.